# Need help finding cycle-s from array or rows based on pattern

Tags: sql, postgresql, cycle

I have a data set which contains certain sequences that have been already found.

The sequence can be as array:

```
    {1288,122,1288,127}
    {286,286,260,260}
```

Or just rows with user, id, site_id

```
    A | 252 | 1288
    A | 253 | 122
    A | 254 | 1288
    A | 255 | 127
```

I am trying to find based on the pattern of the site_id-s, if the array or rows are circular in their manner.

So the first example A-B-A-C is. The second one is not as the sites are 
A-A-B-B. The trick here is that there might be more than one site in-between the sequence and I have yet to find a solution for even the simple A-B-A

I have tried finding some material, but everything refers to string pattern matching or all other types of cycle finding in array, which do not fit my problem.

I only expect to basically get a true or false if that sequence has a cycle in it or not. 
Getting the site-id which is cycling would be a bonus.

Comment: (1) Both of these represent cycles, so I don't understand.  (2) When represented as rows, you need a column that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You could `unnest()` the array `WITH ORDINALITY` and check if in the set two rows exists with the same value but an ordinality at least two apart.

```
WITH 
cte
AS
(
SELECT *
       FROM unnest('{1288,122,1288,127}'::integer[]) WITH ORDINALITY un(v, o)
)
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM cte c1
                      WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                                           FROM cte c2
                                           WHERE c2.v = c1.v
                                                 AND c2.o > c1.o + 1));
```

For the set based problem you'd need a column to order by. But then it's essentially the same. If that column to sort by doesn't allow to directly implement the logic on it, e.g. because it's a string where a + 1 won't work well, you can use `row_number()` to produce suitable ordinals.

To get the numbers that are the "terminals" in a loop (might be more than one) just remove the outer `EXISTS` and project the value.

```
WITH 
cte
AS
(
SELECT *
       FROM unnest('{1288,122,1288,127}'::integer[]) WITH ORDINALITY un(v, o)
)
SELECT v
       FROM cte c1
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM cte c2
                            WHERE c2.v = c1.v
                                  AND c2.o > c1.o + 1);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=cd7e437f943682eb0848fb304d6f86f0)